# What happens if I accidentally duplicate a meta tag in my head?

Tags: html, duplicates, meta-tags

Would there be any duplication errors if I accidentally input more than one meta tag in the head of my code?

For example:

```html
<meta name="description" content="this is a description">
<meta name="description" content="this is also a description">
<meta name="keywords" content="here, are, some, keywords">
```

What would be the outcome? Would both descriptions be accepted? Would the top overwrite the bottom? Would they both be used as one?

Comment: Used where? There isn't one single way to handle meta tags, it is always implementation specific. Meta tags can occur several times and HTML specification doesn't care if there is one or more with the same name. Some applications that use them may combine them, some use the first, some the last, some give an error...

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the meta tag.

You may **not** have multiple …

- [`meta`-`description`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#meta-description) elements:

  > There must not be more than one `meta` element with its `name` attribute set to the value `description` per document.
- [`meta`-`application-name`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#meta-application-name) elements (per language):

  > There must not be more than one `meta` element with a given language and with its `name` attribute set to the value `application-name` per document.

(These two are not necessarily the only meta tags that may not be specified multiple times, but they are the only ones [defined by HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#standard-metadata-names) where this is the case.)

But for most meta tags, it’s not forbidden (and therefore allowed) to specify them multiple times.

A meta tag’s registration would have to define if it’s forbidden to use it multiple times in a document, and if not forbidden, what consumers should do if they encounter multiple occurrences. However, most registrations don’t seem to cover this case, so it’s up to the consumers to come up with something then.

It’s, for example, specified for [multiple `meta`-`keywords` elements](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/54979/17633).